# How to deploy multiple Python-Telegram-Bot (s) in local macOS (As a bot server)?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

So far I am just simply open 2 sessions(I've got 2 bots so far) in macOS 'Terminal' and run the bots.

May I know if there is better way to make those bots alive? Is that the normal way that most of the people will do in this way?

Like this, once the bot is started, then I will just leave the session here for listening the requests.
[image]

Thanks all.

Comment: You could run your bots on a server like AWS, Heroku, or Digital Ocean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Way 1: Run inside docker container**
  You need to install [docker Desktop](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac) at your Mac and run each python script in separate container

  Pros:

  - Modern and correct way to run background processes
  - Running environment independent from local environment

  Cons:

  - You need to install docker
  - You need to know/learn docker
- **Way 2: Run as daemon process inside Linux Virtual Machine [VM]**
  You need to install hypervisor ([VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for example) and install Linux on it. After that use it like server for python scripts.

  Pros:

  - Same as 1

  Cons:

  - You need to install hypervisor
  - You need to know Linux and how to [daemonize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) script (using [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) for example)
  - VM need more resources than docker
- **Way 3: Run process in background** detached from terminal
  Just run `nohup pyton3 /Users/ws_fingear/Documents/workspace/Telegram_Bot/Telegram_Bot_WSFG1.0.py > output.log &`. Mark `&` means that process will be run in background and continue to run even if you close terminal. Output will be printed out inside `output.log` file

  Pros:

  - Super simple

  Cons:

  - Bad way for production environment
  - Can't control or stop running process properly

I guess, you looking for way 3.

Also you can use [syncthing](https://gist.github.com/devster31/dc2888c49d2ed522d68a) on Mac OS to run script as [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) locally

Comment: So if i go for way 3, how can I stop the bot in the background? Could I create another Python script and connect with Flasks so that I could remotely stop the bot by using my browser

Comment: You need to use `kill` command to stop it `kill -9 $(ps aux | grep Telegram_Bot_WSFG1.0.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}' | xargs)` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html